# Pandas - replacing string contents when string contains a period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and want to create a new column based on string contents in two other columns. The rule for concatenating the string depends on the column's contents.

In the table below I want to add `AAL` and `.L` together to get `AAL.L`. In some `Ticker` there's an existing `.`, e.g. row 6 and 10. In these circumstances I don't need two `.` , i.e. I want the the `yticker` to be `AV.L` not `AV..L`

I've tried `str.replace`, but it's not giving me the results that I'd expect.

What's the best way to get the output I need? Either an alternative to `df['yticker'] = df['Ticker'] + df['MktCode']` or using `str.replace` afterwards.

```py
d = {0: {'Ticker': 'AAL', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 1: {'Ticker': 'ABF', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 2: {'Ticker': 'ADM', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 3: {'Ticker': 'AHT', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 4: {'Ticker': 'ANTO', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 5: {'Ticker': 'AUTO', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 6: {'Ticker': 'AV.', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 7: {'Ticker': 'AVST', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 8: {'Ticker': 'AVV', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 9: {'Ticker': 'AZN', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}, 10: {'Ticker': 'BA.', 'Mkt': 'ftse100', 'MktCode': '.L'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).T

df['yticker'] = df['Ticker'] + df['MktCode']
print(df)
```

```
   Ticker      Mkt MktCode yticker
0     AAL  ftse100      .L   AAL.L
1     ABF  ftse100      .L   ABF.L
2     ADM  ftse100      .L   ADM.L
3     AHT  ftse100      .L   AHT.L
4    ANTO  ftse100      .L  ANTO.L
5    AUTO  ftse100      .L  AUTO.L
6     AV.  ftse100      .L   AV..L
7    AVST  ftse100      .L  AVST.L
8     AVV  ftse100      .L   AVV.L
9     AZN  ftse100      .L   AZN.L
10    BA.  ftse100      .L   BA..L
```

```py
df['yticker'] = df['yticker'].str.replace('..L', '.L')
```

Gives:

```
   Ticker      Mkt MktCode yticker
0     AAL  ftse100      .L     ..L
1     ABF  ftse100      .L     A.L
2     ADM  ftse100      .L     A.L
3     AHT  ftse100      .L     A.L
4    ANTO  ftse100      .L    AN.L
5    AUTO  ftse100      .L    AU.L
6     AV.  ftse100      .L     A.L
7    AVST  ftse100      .L    AV.L
8     AVV  ftse100      .L     A.L
9     AZN  ftse100      .L     A.L
10    BA.  ftse100      .L     B.L
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

We can strip the extra `.` from the `Ticker` column before concatenating it with the column `MktCode`

```
df['yticker'] = df['Ticker'].str.rstrip('.') + df['MktCode']
```

---

```
   Ticker      Mkt MktCode yticker
0     AAL  ftse100      .L   AAL.L
1     ABF  ftse100      .L   ABF.L
2     ADM  ftse100      .L   ADM.L
3     AHT  ftse100      .L   AHT.L
4    ANTO  ftse100      .L  ANTO.L
5    AUTO  ftse100      .L  AUTO.L
6     AV.  ftse100      .L    AV.L
7    AVST  ftse100      .L  AVST.L
8     AVV  ftse100      .L   AVV.L
9     AZN  ftse100      .L   AZN.L
10    BA.  ftse100      .L    BA.L
```